# Почему Pos('текст', s) работает намного быстрее чем Pos(memo1.lines[0], s)?

Tags: delphi, строки

**Есть два кода:**

**Код_1:**

```
if ((Pos('Расход', s) > 0) or (Pos('Приход', s) > 0) ) then
  writeln(f1, S);
   end;
```

**Код_2:**

```
if ((Pos(memo1.lines[0], s) > 0) or (Pos(memo1.lines[1], s) > 0) ) then
      writeln(f1, S);
       end;
```

**Вопрос:** Почему **Код_1:** работает намного быстрее, **в раз 10**, чем **Код_2:**. Только из за того что место значений стоит **memo1.lines[0] и memo1.lines[1]**. Или причина в другом ?. И есть вариант исправить это ?

Comment: А длина строк в `Memo` такая же?

Comment: А насколько быстрее? Как измеряли?

Comment: @zed, Тут в memo пишу два слова Расход и Приход. То есть первая строка memo и вторая и программа ищет в текстовом файле все строки где есть эти слова. Но проблема в том что скорость никакая. А если memo убираю и делаю как в Код_1, то скорость нормальная.

Comment: @MAX, Быстрее в раз 10. Измеряла просто создала две программы: С Memo и без него, то есть Код_1 и Код_2: Так вот Код_1: Работает быстрее в раз 10.

Comment: Тогда надо вне цикла сохранить строки из memo в переменные и обращаться уже к ним. Предположу, что тормоза связаны с постоянным копированием строк из memo для передачи их в `Pos`. Ведь, `lines[1]` - ни что иное, как функция, которая возвращает результат (строку).

Comment: @zed, А не подскажите как правильно это сделать, хотя бы пример ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тормоза связаны с постоянным копированием строк из `memo` для передачи их в `Pos`. Ведь, `lines[1]` - ни что иное, как функция, которая возвращает результат (строку).

Чтобы решить проблему, сделайте примерно вот так:

```
var
  s0, s1: string;
begin
...
s0 := memo1.lines[0];
s1 := memo1.lines[1];

while ... do begin
  if (Pos(s0, s) > 0) or (Pos(s1, s) > 0) then
      writeln(f1, S);
end;
```

Comment: Сработало, отлично (Спасибо). И последний вопрос: А если запросов много, то что бы не писать в s0 := memo1.lines[0]; и это s1 := memo1.lines[1]; и это s3 := memo1.lines[2]; Можно как то в цикле это оформить ?

Comment: @Татьяна Можно завести массив `sa: array of string`, заполнить его строками из memo (циклом `for`) и в `Pos` сравнивать с `sa[0]`, `sa[1]` и т.д.