# Не работает цикл \ DelphiXE

Tags: delphi

Не работает цикл:

**Если делаю вот так (то - работает):**

```
while not Eof(f) do
begin
  ReadLn(f, S);
  if  (Pos('Запрос1', s) = 0)
  and (Pos('Запрос2', s) = 0)
  and (Pos('Запрос3', s) = 0)
  and (Pos('Запрос4', s) = 0)
  and (Pos('Запрос5', s) = 0)
  then
    writeln(f1, S);
end;

CloseFile(f);
CloseFile(f1);
```

**А если делаю в цикле (то - не работает):**

```
while not Eof(f) do
begin
  for i:=0 to memo1.Lines.Count-1 do
  begin
    ReadLn(f, S);
    if Pos (memo1.Lines[i], s) = 0 then
      WriteLn(f1, S);
  end;
end;
  CloseFile(f);
  CloseFile(f1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var 
  found: boolean;
  memoLines: TStringList;

...
memoLines := TStringList.Create;
try
  memoLines.AddStrings(memo1.Lines);
  while not Eof(f) do 
  begin
    ReadLn(f, S);
    found := false;
    for i := 0 to memoLines.Count - 1 do
    begin
      if Pos (memoLines[i], s) > 0 then
      begin
        found := true;
        break;
      end;
    end;
    if not found then
    begin
      WriteLn(f1, S);
    end;
  end;
finally
  memoLines.Free;
end;
```

В строке из файла должны присутствовать все ключевые слова, или достаточно хотя бы одного из них?

Comment: О слава Вам Igor, заработал код.... Я уже все нервы истрепала, до этого 30 минут пыталась сама исправить, но увы, не вышло... Спасибо, все замечательно работает!

Comment: Igor еще такой вопрос - Я так понимаю, что скорость упала из за того что:  идет постоянное копированием строк из memo и их передача в Pos.
То есть выходом из этой ситуации будет: вне цикла сохранить строки из memo в переменные и обращаться уже к ним. Буду благодарна за ответ ?

Comment: @Татьяна У Вас вроде был уже на эту тему вопрос? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/887211

Comment: Igor, да, я просто уточнила. Вы профессионал в этом деле. А я прежде чем что то снова делать - всегда пытаюсь посоветоваться, что бы потом не выглядеть глупо. Потому и задала вопрос, премного, премного благодарна Вам!!!